# Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors with parameterized queries

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

```
sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT clientID, clientPassword" & _
                     " FROM Clients" & _
                     " WHERE (clientPassword=?)"
Set param = sqlCmd.CreateParameter("@clientPassword", 200, 1, Len(pass), pass)
sqlCmd.Parameters.Append param

Set rsUsers = sqlCmd.Execute
```

This query executes ok, yet when I try an almost identical one afterwards...

```
sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT clientID, clientUsername, clientPassword" & _
                     " FROM Clients" & _
                     " WHERE (clientEmail=?)"
Set param = sqlCmd.CreateParameter("@clientEmail", 200, 1, Len(email), email)
sqlCmd.Parameters.Append param

Set rsUsers = sqlCmd.Execute
```

I get this error,

> Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.

Both columns are nvarchar, 255 and 50 in length.

Most of my Google searches say this is a datatype error yet I'm only retrieving values and the 2nd query works fine if executed on it's own. The error only occurs if I run more than one query.

Please and thank you.

Thanks Eduardo, that gets me through my queries without errors but my UPDATE query does nothing.

```
sqlCmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Clients" & _ 
                     " SET clientUsername=?, clientPassword=?" & _ 
                     " WHERE (clientEmail=?)" 
Set param = sqlCmd.CreateParameter("@clientEmail", 200, 1, Len(email), email)    
sqlCmd.Parameters.Append param 
Set param = sqlCmd.CreateParameter("@clientUsername", 200, 1, Len(user), user)
sqlCmd.Parameters.Append param 
Set param = sqlCmd.CreateParameter("@clientPassword", 200, 1, Len(pass), pass)    
sqlCmd.Parameters.Append param 
Set rsUsers = sqlCmd.Execute
```

Any idea why? I've been stuck on this piece of code for days.

Comment: Are the clientPassword and clientEmail columns of the same datatype and same length?  Is the value of the email variable longer than the clientEmail column?

Comment: Are you reusing the same sqlCmd? If so the sqlCmd.Parameters has two parameters instead of one. Use a different sqlCmd or use sqlCmd.Refresh.

Answer (score 2):

Do you reinitialize the `sqlCmd` variable?

I guess you are missing

```
Set sqlCmd = server.createobject("ADODB.Command")
```

After running the second one

**Edit after your edit**
The order matters, so you need to add the params in the same order that you use them in the query

```
Set param = sqlCmd.CreateParameter("@clientUsername", 200, 1, Len(user), user)
sqlCmd.Parameters.Append param 
Set param = sqlCmd.CreateParameter("@clientPassword", 200, 1, Len(pass), pass)    
sqlCmd.Parameters.Append param 
Set param = sqlCmd.CreateParameter("@clientEmail", 200, 1, Len(email), email)    
sqlCmd.Parameters.Append param     
Set rsUsers = sqlCmd.Execute
```

Comment: Please see revised question. I couldn't get the formatting right on the comment.

Comment: I don't believe that is correct. You're saying I need 3 different objects when in fact Parameters is a collection. Tried it anyway and it didn't help.

Comment: After I Append the param, I re-set it and use it again. That shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Also: the order matters, so you need to add the params in the same order that you use them in the query

Comment: Cool, that's what did it finally. Every tutorial I've seen only shows how to add one so they are of limited usefulness. Re-using param 3 times worked fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: There's nothing technically wrong with reusing the `param` variable.  Each `Set param = sqlCmd.CreateParameter(...)` line creates a new Parameter object and sets `param` to be a reference to the new object.  In this case, it was the order of the params that needed to be fixed.